# Is it better to use HTML5 & Canvas or CSS3(background image) & jquery to make a slideshow?

Tags: jquery, canvas, cpu, css, slideshow

I'm making a slideshow and the images won't be static, they'll be pulled in dynamically through an array and finally it will look like this:

What i'm wondering is, what is more CPU friendly, CSS3 & jQuery making transitions fade simply by changing the CSS class of the div that will fill the screen, *or*, Canvas with  drawn on it refreshing each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webkit (Safari, Chrome, etc.) has built-in support for CSS-based transitions effects, and Mozilla is working on adding them as well. Being able to use the browser-supplied transitions, where available, will definitely provide a performance boost.

I'm not sure what your browser compatibility requirements are, but keep in mind that no version of IE supports `<canvas>` yet. You can use a JavaScript library to provide it with pseudo-support, but I would imagine that's going to lead to a performance hit.

Comment: I think that you made my choice pretty simple and you gave me a good reason to why I should use CSS3 and on top of that, why not canvas.. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use HTML5, but there is nothing stopping you... in fact, here is a slideshow about HTML5 (*Using* **HTML5**)!

http://slides.html5rocks.com/

Comment: Nice link, really shows what we allready can accomplish with HTML5, can come in handy! thanks!

Comment: This must have just happened recently - I'm looking for a clean link now.

Answer (score 2):

Given the sad state affairs we are in at the moment where IE doesn't support `CANVAS` then I'd say stick with the jQuery version. Unless, of course, you don't mind excluding IE - but bare in mind it's still by far the most popular browser out there.

I'd also say that sliders aren't that CPU intensive and I would always put maintainability and compatibility first.

Comment: I've been totally ignoring the fact that IE doesn't support canvas yet and the only reason is that I want to see the final outcome of the site which is very wrong. As i have understood it IE9 will support canvas but it's still not here yet.

I think i'll recode the page to use css3 since it's implemented to almost all the browsers by now, and it really shouldn't slow down a PC in this "modern" world..! thanks for your input

Comment: @Noor - MSFT has stated support for SVG in IE9 (as well as many other things, but AFAIK they have not yet stated they will support CANVAS)

Answer (score 2):

Plenty of options came into my mind:

1. Transitions by JS/CSS are well-tested & quick to implement. CPU usage is unlikely to be a problem.
2. However, if you want to experience with the canvas option *and* support the Redmond-based browsing-thingy, you can simplify your life by drawing through [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) cross-browser API.
3. [Pure CSS transitions](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Animations/Animations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008032-CH6-SW1) are the most elegant (arguably) method. Unfortunately folks outside Cupertino have been lazy to implement them, so their use is currently mostly limited to [impressive](http://www.westciv.com/tools/3Dtransforms/index.html) extra eye candy.
4. Retro way: pretend it's 2001 and [these guys](http://adobe.com) enables you to do some serious CPU burning for few hundred bucks.